# Portable microsoft office 2007 quick access toolbar

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007, portable

I am using microsoft office 2007 on several PCs and I transfer Quick access toolbar settings from one PC to another by copying .qat files from

```
C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office
```

Now I've decided to move to a portable version of office to always have a flash stick with soft that I need with me, but the problem is, that I don't know where does portable version stores its Quick access configuration.

Inside of folder with portable version I have another folder that seems to keep files required for program to work, it looks like this:

[image]

- The first thing that came to my mind was to add a subfolder like

  *%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Office*

  to that folder and copy .qat files there, but that didn't help.
- Neither this portable version stores that settings in their usual location.
  But if I transfer my usb stick to another PC the settings are lost. Seems like it stores them somewhere on current PC, outside of usb stick, but not in their usual location.

Maybe someone who is familiar with portable soft creation can help me to know where that location can be, because the idea of portable soft itself is lost, when you cannot carry your settings with you.

Comment: Microsoft do not have a portable version of office. Where are you getting yours from?

Comment: I downloaded portable version from internet of course.
And I have just solved my problem by getting another version, where folder _%LocalAppData%_ existed inside program folder, and so I was able to transfer settings well. Now I have perfect working soft always with me, I dont know if this post should be removed, or stay here so other people with same problem can try the solution that helped me.